# How far does the scope of an entityManager reach?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, java-ee-7

Let's say I have a stateless session bean, Foo. I have injected an EntityManager into Foo using CDI.

I've read that by default, the EntityManager will be transaction-scoped and that therefore any entities that are in the EntityManager's persistence context will be managed by the EntityManager until the end of the transaction.

But what if the transaction starts outside of Foo, in class Bar? So Foo has been injected into Bar, the transaction starts in Bar and then Foo is called within that transaction. Of course, the EntityManager can't manage objects before Foo is created, but what about after the method in Foo returns?

After Foo returns, is the EntityManager somehow still managing the entities it was managing in Foo or have they been detached at that point even though the transaction is still continuing? If I change a value on an entity in Bar after the method in Foo returned, should that change get propagated to the database?

Many thanks!

Edit: Some code to make it clearer

```
class Bar {

    @Inject
    Foo foo;

    // Transaction starts here
    public void doSomething(){
        foo.doSomethingElse();

        // Transaction is still uncommitted here
        // Make a change to an entity here that was in foo's 
        // entityManager's persistence context
        // Does it get picked up and propagated to the db? 
        // Or is the entityManager gone by this point?
    }
    // Transaction commits after return of this method
}



@Stateless
class Foo {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    // This method by default joins the transaction that was already started in Bar
    public void doSomethingElse(){
        // Do something with entities
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on how your transaction boundaries are managed.  are you using bean managed transactions?  container managed with REQUIRES_NEW?  container managed with default boundaries?

i recommend:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm thinking of container-managed transactions. So by default, the container starts a transaction in Bar, which is joined by default by Foo. When Foo returns, is the EntityManager declared in Foo still live?

Comment: it is the same EM.  if you're in the same TX, you get the same EM instance.   so if you begin a TX in method one() inside bean Foo, and Foo calls method two() inside bean Bar, and it's not annotated to create a new TX (aka you're continuing in the same TX) the injected EM for that instance will be the same.

Comment: Ah, I'm talking about things the other way round. Bar calls Foo. The entityManager is in Foo. The method in Foo ends and we're back in Bar. Is the entityManager (that is only defined in Foo) still active in Bar? We're in the same transaction..

Comment: yes.  it's still the same TX, so it's the same EM instance.  doesn't matter.  except i'm curious why this matters, if you're not injecting the EM into Bar, then why do you care?

Comment: Because let's say we're back in Bar after the Foo method completes. If I change an entity that was managed by Foo's EntityManager, then the way JPA works, JPA should scan that entity for any changes right up to the point where the TX ends. But I'm curious about whether that will happen, especially if Foo is now out of scope (which it could be)

Comment: remember the EM is tied to the TX.  session beans are just proxies so the concept of "instance" is loose.  just because Foo goes back into the pool has no effect on the EM because it's still tied to the current TX.

Comment: Ah.. Did not realize that the EM is tied to the TX.. Thanks for your help! Marking your answer as correct :-)